# .map() through keys with a Mobx Observable Map

Tags: mobx

I define a Map like this:

```
class A {
  @observable myMap = new Map();
}
```

And in a react component:

```
class B extends Component {
  store = new A();

  render() {
    const { myMap } = this.store;

    return <div>
      {/* I want to do the equivalent of this: */}
      {Object.keys(myMap).map(key => <p>{key}: {myMap.get(key)}</p>)}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

This might be a simple question, but I didn't find how to do that, apart from converting `myMap` to a normal JS object with `toJs()`, which I don't want to do.

Googling didn't help much with map, Map, object... keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the map spec and mobx documentation: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html

you can call the `.keys()` directly on the map:

```
{myMap.keys().map(key => <p>{key}: {myMap.get(key)}</p>)}
```

Edit: excuse me i didn't realise iterator doesnt contain map function. You can make your own:

## Solution

You can create your own iterator map function:

```js
var x = new Map();
x.set('test','asdf')

console.log(map(x.keys(),(x) => 'prefix:'+x ))

function map(iterator, mapFn){
  var result = [];
  for(var item of iterator){
    result.push(mapFn(item)); 
  }
  return result;
}
```

another solution is turing iterator into array:

```
Array.from(map.keys()).map(...) // array map function of all keys.
```

## hacky prototype method

You can make an extension method in a bit of hacky way, probably does not work for all browsers!:

```
//Warning this hacky way:
var t = new Map();
t.keys().__proto__.map = function(mapFn){
  return map(this, mapFn);
}

t.keys().map(x=> x) // now usable!
```

Comment: `TypeError: myMap.keys(...).map is not a function`

Comment: @amaurymartiny excuse me didnt know iterator missing map function. i added a solution.

Comment: Removed the -1 and put a +1. But I didn't accept this answer, because it stills seems a lot of work for something simple. I even prefer the `Object.keys(toJs(myMap)).map(...)` solutioj

Comment: @amaurymartiny Object.keys => on map is just `map.keys()` you can do though: `Array.from(map.keys()).map(...)`

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Accepted the answer.

Comment: [...map.keys()].map(...)